# VS Code "Cannot find or open the PDB file" even though the pdb exists and it loads other csproj pdb files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm launching a web api project and I noticed the problem when I tried to set a breakpoint in the logic layer (which is a separate csproj) and it showed unverified breakpoint.

Digging into it I found that the Debug console shows "Cannot find or open the PDB file" even though the pdb file exists in the directory it searches AND it can load the other 7 csproj dll's that are in the same directory.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, deleting the repo and recloning, restarting my computer, etc. Not sure how to proceed or what other information to provide. Please help because this will keep me from using vs code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting debug type to portable in the csproj file worked.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
   <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This does not work for VSCode . Didnt try for visual studio, this shouldnt be the accepted answer !

Comment: This was so long ago I don't remember the details. But if I accepted it then it solved the issue for me. I'm still using VS Code for dotnet core development to this day. Did you solve your problem with a different solution? You can post it and I'll accept that one if it's a more general solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try Tools-> Options-> Debugging-> Symbols. Select checkbox "Microsoft Symbol Servers".
 Visual Studio will download PDBs automatically. Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: I'm using vs code. They're also my own csproj files. It shouldn't need to download them. They're all in a bin that the debugger is aware of (I say this because it finds the other csproj pdb files)